# JQuery Classes Count in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML which is receive input from users.  My job is to count cards they enter and style these cards.  Cards are placed inside `<section>`.

Problems: My Jquery is only counting and works well in one section.  If users enter more than one sections, the code doesn't work.  My code below shows when users enter 2 sections: cards in first section should be blue and cards in second section should be red, but now they are all blue.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7pthuny/)

```js
var numCard = $('.cards').length;
if (numCard == "2") {
  /* $('.cards').css('color', 'red'); */
  $("section .cards").parent().addClass("two-cards");
} else if (numCard == "3") {
  $("section .cards").parent().addClass("three-cards");
} else {
  $('section .cards').parent().addClass("four-cards");
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.two-cards .cards {
  color: red;
}

.three-cards .cards {
  color: green;
}

.four-cards .cards {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="cards">
    First Card
  </div>
  <div class="cards">
    Second Card
  </div>
  <div class="cards">
    Third Card
  </div>
  <div class="cards">
    Third Card
  </div>
</section>
<p>

  <section>
    <div class="cards">
      First Card
    </div>
    <div class="cards">
      Second Card
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: `if (numCard == "2")`  Why are you comparing an integer variable coercely with a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/d067k5L9/2/)**

You need to loop through the sections, then use `this` keyword to check :

```js
$('section').each(function() {
  var numCard = $('.cards', this).length;

  if (numCard == "2") {
    $(this).addClass("two-cards");
  } else if (numCard == "3") {
    $(this).addClass("three-cards");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("four-cards");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.two-cards .cards {
  color: red;
}

.three-cards .cards {
  color: green;
}

.four-cards .cards {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="cards">
    First Card
  </div>
  <div class="cards">
    Second Card
  </div>
  <div class="cards">
    Third Card
  </div>
  <div class="cards">
    Third Card
  </div>
</section>
<p>
  <section>
    <div class="cards">
      First Card
    </div>
    <div class="cards">
      Second Card
    </div>
  </section>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi Zakaria Acharki, thank you very much. That works well!

Comment: You're welcome, Glad I could help. If any answer helps you vote it up, if any answer is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** For the future readers.

Comment: I just voted yours as a correct answer.  I have a question: What does "this" mean (represent) in this code `var numCard = $('.cards', this).length;`?

Comment: You can vote it UP too, it will be helpful, whatever ( It's a shorthand of `var numCard = $(this).find('.cards').length;`